# Thousands of Reporters Integrated in Parallel (TRIP) barcodes

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, cloning

Has anyone worked with constructing barcodes for TRIP? How does constructing of barcodes work in general? I don't seem to be able to grasp the basics of constructing these barcodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nprot.2014.072) and [user manual](http://trip.nki.nl/trip/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=trip0.5.zip) it seems that barcodes are random sequences of pre-defined length of 16-20bp ± 1bp. On data analysis step they are combined and all barcodes 2 Hamming distance apart (it means that two words have difference in one letter from each other) will be discarded from the list of genuine barcodes.